# loop javascript with css content

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, html-lists

i need in my code to repeat ten times this content, then i think that is possible in a loop like a for or while, but i tried and i can't

```
<li>
    <img style="float: left;" src="img/gaja.jpg" alt="Angry face" />
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 20px; float:left; margin-left: 5px; font: bold 12px arial;">IceMan</div>
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 20px; float:left; margin-left:5px;">Web Designer / FullTime</div>
</li>
```

any help?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var li = $('li');
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    li.clone().appendTo(li.parent());
}
```

Comment: why do u need jquery for something so trivial?

Comment: I think its jsut because jQuery is used for everything nowadays.. simple or not, jQuery makes it easy :)

Comment: Our whole life is a collection of trivial pieces. Feel free to use it that makes life easier

Comment: Is the answer really that simple? Is saving 3 lines always better than linking to several kilobytes of JavaScript library? (=another request) :)

Comment: But I of course agree with the fact, that jQuery code is much nicer :)

Comment: the problem is not the library, i use the jquery in my project. the code is perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since the jQuery was not specified in the inital question I am going to assume it is not being used.

The pure JavaScript way would be like so:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
    ul.appendChild(li.cloneNode(true));
}
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/RMVkk/).**

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    document.write('<li>');
    document.write('<img style="float: left;" src="img/gaja.jpg" alt="Angry face" />');
    document.write('<div style="width: 100px; height: 20px; float:left; margin-left: 5px; font: bold 12px arial;">IceMan</div>');
    document.write('<div style="width: 150px; height: 20px; float:left; margin-left:5px;">Web Designer / FullTime</div>');
    document.write('</li>');
}
```

Comment: You can use really basic and pure JavaScript approach like this if you don't rely on JavaScript too much.

Comment: There are already posted better ways to do it. Mine was just the most basic one :)